# Pass data to jQuery.Ajax() that can be retrieved in the global error handler?

Tags: jquery

I setup the ajax error handler something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxError( ajaxErrorHandler );

function ajaxErrorHandler (e, jqXHR, settings, exception)
{

}
```

When I call `$.ajax(options);` I wish to pass a DOM element along w/ the ajax call so that I could read it in `ajaxErrorHandler()`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using $.ajax() itself to run your requests, then you can do this. Convenience methods like $.post won't work.

Per the jQuery docs (and the signature in your example handler), the ajaxError handler receives the original settings object sent to $.ajax. You can add a reference to your DOM element in this settings object. The $.ajax method will ignore it, but it'll pass it along with your other settings to the handlers!

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/kittens',
    data: $('#puppies').serialize(),
    elm: $('#puppies')
});
```

Then, in the handler, you can retrieve the #puppies form with `settings.elm`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
     //your catch code.
    }
});
```

This creates a global jQuery AJAX solution. You can capture the following with it:

> > > HTTP Status Code 404 Error – ajax file not found error
> > >       HTTP Status Code 500 Error – ajax internal system error
> > >       AJAX JSON Parse Errors
> > >       jQuery AJAX Timeout Errors
> > >       jQuery AJAX Abort Errors
> > >       Browser/Connectivity Errors
> > >       AJAX no transport error
> > >       Other Unknown Errors

It works with $.post, $.get $.ajax. 
**More information and examples can be found at:** 
[**>>Full jQuery Ajax Error Handling Function Example**](http://www.unseenrevolution.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function/)